# if statement results being echoed twice in for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop, if-statement

http://codepad.org/VnqZjQ7e

All the code is in there so that this time I don't mess up in forgetting code like last time.

Basically if you run it in your host server you will see that the plans are listed above the table which is what I want to prevent, but the thing is I don't even know where it comes from, and the other problem being how I would fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this portion of your code

```
if($basicplan < $suckersplan && $basicplan < $compplan)
    echo $bestplan = $basicname;
if($compplan < $basicplan && $compplan < $suckersplan)
    echo $bestplan = $compname;
if($suckersplan < $basicplan && $suckersplan < $compplan)
    echo $bestplan = $suckersname;
```

That's echoing outside of the  elements. Instead, use the following.

```
if($basicplan < $suckersplan && $basicplan < $compplan)
    $bestplan = $basicname;
if($compplan < $basicplan && $compplan < $suckersplan)
    $bestplan = $compname;
if($suckersplan < $basicplan && $suckersplan < $compplan)
    $bestplan = $suckersname;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix. It appears that i still have much to learn about coding.

Comment: You're very welcome, you might want to consider using else ifs, as they would certainly help you out here. The great part is that you're learning, and you appear to be motivated :) If my answer helps solve your problem, please "Accept" it :)